# How to add button with Children.Add in code behind?How to add clicked to button

Tags: xamarin, button, code-behind

Adding a button in a stacklayout does not give me a place to add a name for the button.

```
var sl = new StackLayout
            {
                Children = {
                    new Button {Text="Click Me"},
}
};
```

How do I add a name to the button so I can add the button.clicked event?

Comment: The button itself most likely has a ClickedEvent property that you can set when you are initializing your button. Also, why not do it in xaml?

Comment: To add button to the page and add clicked event to the button in code behind, you could refer to the tutorial:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/button#creating-a-button-in-code The x:Name attribute is used in xaml instead of code behind. Check the doc:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/xaml/xaml-basics/get-started-with-xaml?tabs=windows#xaml-and-code-interactions

Comment: Thank you very much. I am aware of those techniques but my issue arose when I was creating the button in a stacklayout, which does not provide for a way to name the button. Code follows: var sl2 = new StackLayout {
                Children = {
                    new Button {Text="GoBack",
                    Style=(Style)Application.Current.Resources["MyButtons"] },

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How to add button with Children.Add in code behind?How to add clicked to button

To add button to the page and add clicked event to the button in code behind, try the following code:

```
Button button = new Button
{
    Text = "Button",
    VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.CenterAndExpand,
    HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center
};
button.Clicked += Click_Event;

Content = new StackLayout
{
    Children =
    {
        button
    }
};

private void Click_Event(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    throw new NotImplementedException();
}
```

Tutorial:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/button#creating-a-button-in-code

> How do I add a name to the button so I can add the button.clicked event?

The `x:Name` attribute is used in xaml instead of code behind.
Check the doc:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/xaml/xaml-basics/get-started-with-xaml?tabs=windows#xaml-and-code-interactions

Answer (score 0):

use a normal C# object reference

```
Button button;

var sl = new StackLayout
{
  Children = {
    (button = new Button {Text="Click Me"})
  }
};

button.Clicked += MyClickedHandler;
```

`x:Name` in XAML is not an actual object property, it is just used as a convenience to generate an object reference by the XAML tools.